# Persistant variables in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I'm using streambuilder for a chat application. However as soon as the page loads, I use a function to retrieve the user details from firebase. And it works fine but when the streambuilder refreshes, it goes back to the initial state, taking the initial value of the user details. (Code explained below):

```
String myName = "me";       ////Here is where I initialize the variables(ID AND NAME)
String id = '1';
Stream<QuerySnapshot> chats;
TextEditingController messageEditingController = TextEditingController();
bool isLoading = true;

Widget chatMessages() {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: chats,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.hasData
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return MessageTile(
                image: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["imgUrl"],
                message: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["message"],
                sendByMe:
                    myName == snapshot.data.documents[index].data["sendBy"],  ////////This variable for name work fine when the screen loads but as soon as the stream refreshes, it takes the value from where it was initialized (Line 1 and 2). How do I get it to use only the value I get from the function?
              );
            })
        : Center(
            child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
            radius: 18,
          ));
  },
);
}
@override
void initState() {
getUserDetails();               /////function called inside init
setState(() {
  isLoading = false;
});                                
super.initState();
}

void getUserDetails() async {                        //////Here is where I fetch the user details.
UserModel user = await AuthService().getUser();
id = user.iD;
myName = user.name;
}
```

Comment: have you declared your variables inside of build method? If yes, that may be the reason. Each time you refresh it calls build method again, which is initialized again to the values in the code. Try putting it outside the build method.

Comment: Your answer partially helped, now when I open the screen, it loads the initial data first but when I close it and reopen it, it loads the new data.For some reason it uses the initial user values when it loads the first time but after closing and opening again, it loads the proper data... Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What do you want to happen, should it load initial data upon reopening or you dont want it to happen? If you dont want new data to be applied when reopening , you can try reconstructing the class again by a constructor each time you want to open it.

Comment: It's a chat app basically, when I open it, it should retrieve user data and use it to display the chats. Right now what it does is, before retrieving the data, it shows chats for the initial values that I provide when declaring variable like String userID=1, so it displays data for userID 1 and then when I reopen, it retrieves the data and shows chats for the proper user. If you didnt understand the question, I can explain a bit more

Comment: Add a new question with full code and your queries. Here informations are less.